# Create a list from file and find max value

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
file = open('data.txt') 
data = [] 

h = [i[:-1] for i in file] 

def maximum_cols(list):
    for line in h:
        data.append(line)
y = [int(n) for n in data]

    x = None
    for value in data:
        value = int(value)
        if not x: 
            x = value 
        elif value > x:
            x = value
    return x
maximum_cols(data)
print(data)
```

So I'm trying to read a file into 2d list and then find the max value from the list and print it out. I'm so lost and stuck. I'm not sure how to proceed. Here's the code I made. I'm pretty sure there's some errors in my coding. I'm new to python and I need assistance

Contents of **Data.txt:**

```
13 45 44 98 1 17 4
2 0 1 3 1 1 1
```

[DataFile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTX6z.png)

[Code's; Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vze9P.png)

Comment: can you provide a sample file? and what is the current output?

Comment: @OferSadan See edit for the file.

Comment: why post a image when you can copy paste the content?

Comment: How is this relevant to what I'm asking?

Comment: Well because it would be easy for people trying to help you.. _so they can easily copy paste_ it instead of typing each and every value from the image..

Comment: @unown Check out my answer and see if you understand. Because I tested it and it works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have rewritten the code in a simpler way. Try it and see. It works:

```
file = open('data.txt') 
data = [] 

data = [i[:-1] for i in file]

def maximum_cols():

    max = 0 
    for line in data:
        x = line.split(' ')
        for num in x:
            if(num > max):
                max = num
    return max

print(maximum_cols())
```

I have used most of your variable naming. But I only tried to make it shorter and simpler to understand. Is this what you were looking for?

EDIT:

```
file = open('data.txt') 
data = [] 

data = [i[:-1] for i in file]

def maximum_cols():

    max = 0 
    for line in data:
        x = line.split(' ')
        for num in x:
            if(num > max):
                max = num
    for line in data:
        if max in line:
            return line

print(maximum_cols())
```

Try and see if the extra for loop works for you.

EDIT 2:

Try this for the square brackets:

```
file = open('data.txt') 
data = [i[:] for i in file]

def maximum_cols():
    max = 0 
    for line in data:
        x = line.strip().split(' ')
        for num in x:
            if(int(num) > max):
                max = int(num)
    for line in data:
        if str(max) in line:
            return ('[' + line.strip() + ']')

print(maximum_cols())
```

Hope it works! :)

Comment: Getting an typeError

Comment: Im sorry to hear that. It works for me. Are you getting the type error in another part of your program where you are using the value of max?

Comment: Trying to work it out. It works for me, so googling a bit

Comment: I fix it, but how can I get it to print the list instead of 98? so like :[13 45 44 98 1 17 4]

Comment: Here's the output: 13 45 44 98 1 17 4 How can I make it like this: [13 45 44 98 1 17 4] So it have the bracket?

Comment: Thank you! Just What I need.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, when you are calling `maximum_cols(data)` your are doing it without a variable, and later you print out the same `data` which is the 2d-list, so you're not even printing the max.

Secondly, you have some problems with getting the list itself from the file, you have to split each line first.

```
myfile = open('data.txt') # don't use the word file as a variable
data = [line.rstrip().split() for line in myfile]
myfile.close() # very important to close files after we use them
```

With `rstrip()` we get all the lines without newline chars and without getting ugly with [:-1] which is unreadable and very breakable (rstrip is just for that) and then `split()` the lines to get each item

Notice that `data` is now already the 2-d list you wanted, but still strings and not integers, now we can get out max value with the builtin max function and with some fancy list comprehension, this can be done with one line function:

```
def max2d(data):
    return max(int(x) for line in data for x in line)
```

Then you just need to use that function and print the output:

```
mymax = max2d(data)
print(mymax)
```

Everything together:

```
myfile = open('data.txt') # don't use the word file as a variable
data = [line.rstrip().split() for line in myfile]
myfile.close() # very important to close files after we use them

def max2d(data):
    return max(int(x) for line in data for x in line)

mymax = max2d(data)
print(mymax)
```

As you can see I allowed myself to break from your style because I thought it would be better to learn the more "pythonic" way to do this... Hope that helps

Comment: No need to load the whole file in memory with `myfile.readlines()` - `myfile` will suffice. You also don't need the `str.rstrip()` as `str.split()` will ignore heading and trailing whitespace by default.

Comment: Agreed of the first point, and edited my answer to match, but on the second point i wanted to show him something better than `[:-1]` that he used, so I kept `rstrip()`

Answer (score 0):

The biggest problem with your existing code (apart from weird indenting and a bit of inefficiency) is that you never split your current row into digits to be used for comparison.

What you're trying to achieve is relatively simple - following your logic you can separate the file loading/2D list generation and actually finding out the largest value in the list:

```
def get_data(filename):
    with open(filename, "r") as f:  # open the file
        return [list(map(int, x.split())) for x in f]  # generate the 2D integer table

def get_max_value(data):
    return max(max(x) for x in data)  # get maximum value out of all maximums of each row
```

You can then test it as:

```
your_data = get_data("data.txt")  # your 2D list
# e.g. [[13, 45, 44, 98, 1, 17, 4], [2, 0, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1]]
max_value = get_max_value(your_data)  # the maximum value 
# e.g. 98
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
    data = [] 
    with open('pytext.txt','rb') as f:
        line = f.read().splitlines()

    for i in line:
        data =  i.split(' ')
        str_list = map(lambda x: x.strip(), data)
        mylist =   [int(i) for i in str_list if i]
        print max(mylist)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you a much simpler way. Use **List comprehensions**

**Data.txt**

```
13 45 44 98 1 17 4
2 0 1 3 1 1 1
```

**Look** at this code:

```
ff = open("data.txt","r+")
flist = ff.readlines()
flist = [item.split() for item in flist]
flist = [int(x) for sub_list in flist for x in sub_list]
print(max(flist))
```

Output:

```
98
```

Now your `flist = ff.readlines()` just reads each and every line and stores every line as a list. It's output would be,

```
['13 45 44 98 1 17 4\n', '2 0 1 3 1 1 1\n']
```

Now the first list comprehension,

```
flist = [item.split() for item in flist]
```

The above line splits those lines into individual *numbers*. Output would be this,

```
[['13', '45', '44', '98', '1', '17', '4'], ['2', '0', '1', '3', '1', '1', '1']]
```

The final list comprehension

```
flist = [int(x) for sub_list in flist for x in sub_list]
```

Just `extends` or *merges* all of those items into a single list and changes them to an `int`. It's output would be,

```
[13, 45, 44, 98, 1, 17, 4, 2, 0, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1]
```

Finally just use built-in `max()` function to get the max of the list.

```
max(flist)
```

See how simple it is. However if you are looking to solve the problem in your specific code take a look at other solultions. I just mentioned you a **much simpler way**

Comment: The output should return a list so : [13 45 44 98 1 17 4]

Comment: You **should have mentioned that** then

Comment: My fault. Didn't notice until I saw the output

Comment: Did you notice because you didn't mention..every solution here by everyone's effort has become pointless ..

Answer (score 0):

Just use `heapq` to store the lines, after splitting and mapping to `int`. You can use `nlargest` to pull out only the largest entry according to which one contains the highest value.

```
from heapq import heappush, nlargest

with open('data.txt') as f:
    heap = []
    for line in f:
        heappush(heap, map(int, line.split()))

    print(nlargest(1, heap, key=max)[0])
```

Output:

```
[13, 45, 44, 98, 1, 17, 4]
```

If you just want the single largest value in all lists (not sure you do), use `itertools.chain.from_iterable` to flatten the 2d list into a single iterable and get the `max` of that.

```
from itertools import chain

with open('data.txt') as f:
    mval = max(chain.from_iterable(map(int,line.split()) for line in f))

    print(mval)
```